# How to save to datagridview from access (vb.net)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am currently working on a timetable program and currently have a DataGridView in which the user enters data and should be able to save that data so when the program is opened again that data is still there. I have tried many options but nothing seems to work. I currently have this code:

```
        Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Daily_formatBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.Daily_formatTableAdapter.Update(Me.CalenderD1DataSet.Daily_format)
        MsgBox("Update successful")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Update failed")
    End Try
```

Comment: Just a guess from your tags, but are you using this with Microsoft Access? If so, you should use the [tag:ms-access] tag instead of [tag:access] (see the usage guidance for the latter).

Comment: We can only guess what you want to do. Maybe this will do what you want: `DataGridView.Enabled = False DataGridView.ReadOnly = True`

Comment: You did not tell us *what* isnt working

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code from one of my programs that saves data from a Datagridview into a database, you should get the idea:

```
 For i = 0 To DG_add_stock.Rows.Count - 1

     Dim stock_code As String = CStr(DG_add_stock.Rows(i).Cells("Code").Value)
     Dim stock_desc As String = CStr(DG_add_stock.Rows(i).Cells("Description").Value)
     Dim qty As String = CStr(DG_add_stock.Rows(i).Cells("Qty").Value)
     Dim price As String = CStr(DG_add_stock.Rows(i).Cells("Price").Value)
     Dim tax_rate As String = CStr(DG_add_stock.Rows(i).Cells("Tax_Rate").Value)
     Dim line_total As String = CStr(DG_add_stock.Rows(i).Cells("Line_Total").Value)

     ''' Save the data in a database or update existing data

 Next
```

And then to show the data:

```
DG_Maintenance_Stock.Rows.Clear()

''' Get the data from the database

For add_items = 0 To row_count - 1

    ''' Load values from each row

    DG_Maintenance_Stock.Rows.Add(code_list, desc_list, qty_list, tax_rate_list, price_list)

    DG_Maintenance_Stock.Sort(maintenance_stock_Code, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

Next
```